# How to index and query data which is not available at index time using solr

Tags: java, solr

In one one of my application we need to index huge data (30GB). We are using SOLR to index this data. we have 50 field in our schema.xml. I am indexing data from different databases.

But at the time of indexing all the fields data is not available. So we have created multiple cores and indexing each core separately.

Ex:- using Core 0 we are indexing 5 fields using separate query

Select  Field1 ,Field2 ,Field3 ,Field4 ,Field5 from dual.

Field1 ---  Common field across cores
Field2  --- Field which is indexed in this core
Field3  -- Field which is indexed in this core
Field4  -- Field which is indexed in this core
Field5  -- Field which is indexed in this core

So rest all field in core0 will be null other than the above 5 fields.

Next for core 1

Core 1 we are indexing 3 fields using separate query

Select  Field1 ,Field6 ,Field6  from dual.

Field1 ---  Common field across cores
Field6  --- Field which is indexed in this core
Field7  -- Field which is indexed in this core

We are using common schema.xml for all cores.

For querying we wrote a custom request handler which queries each core separately and then merge the results. Also the data in each core will get refreshed every 3 hours. I have tried partial update feature in solr4.0, but it too takes much time to index...... not so helpful

Is their any better approach/design to handler this problem?

Thanks,
ravi

Comment: what do you exactly mean with "all fields data is not available at index time"? i can really help you, but i don't exactly understand your question... NB: update your post with some examples and a larger explanation, don't comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shards` to query across multiple cores. You can do this from any code.

e.g.;

```
solr/core1/select/?q=iPad&shards=localhost:8983/solr/core1,localhost:8983/solr/core0
```

You can pass the as many cores as you want with "," in `shards`.

Comment: Currently i am using shards to query... but in my current design AND operation will not work since in core0 will have data for only 5 fields and rest of the fields are null... similarly in core1 only some field will be filled with data and rest of the fields will be null, since we are loading core0,core1 separately  using different sources. Only OR operation will work in this scenario....